# WatchKit perform task when app inactive

Tags: ios, background-process, watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit

I am creating a standalone app for Apple Watch that measure heart beat rate every 30mn and send them to the server.
I am referring to [this](https://github.com/coolioxlr/watchOS-2-heartrate) projet to extract the heart beat rate. The project contain a class that extract this measure via HealthKit.

What I need to do is to make this task running permanently, even if the app in inactive. And be able to disable it via a settings view in my app.

So my question is: how to perform a task permanently in background in an Apple Watch application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look what they say in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKWorkoutSession_ClassReference/index.html):

> Workout sessions let apps continue to run in the foreground.

So you app can gather heart rate information while app is inactive. Then you can use `workoutSession(_:didChangeToState:fromState:date:)` method and split information into 30 minute intervals according to **date** property.

> If your application is suspended, the delegate receives this call
>   after the application resumes. This means you may receive the
>   notification long after the state changed. Check the date parameter to
>   determine when the state change actually occurred.

Finally you can send information to server when app becomes active.

### UPD:

You also can call `openParentApplication:reply:` inside `workoutSession(_:didChangeToState:fromState:date:)` to send stats to server in the background (on iphone).